# Want to save pulseaudio output as wav or mp3

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio, cat, audio-recording

Recently I have discovered

```
cat file.bmp | padsp tee | aplay
```

But I dont know, how to save the output of this command as audio file.
If it would help, I have sox and lame software(I dont know how to properly use it).

Comment: If you read the man-page for 'aplay' ('man aplay' in a terminal) you would have found it's sister-command  .. 'arecord'.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I realized it was very silly, to put that question without reading man page.

Comment: There is something wrong w arecord. When I use aplay, there is some noise, but arecord created files is only silence. Maybe I have to use aplay to play and arecord to record played stuff?